# How to conduct an exact Fisher test when I have more than two groups in Python?

Tags: python, statistical-test

My data is the following:

```
prfs
ex  F   M
Pref        
C   11  20
B   15  6
A   3   5
```

I would like to make an exact Fisher test.  There is a function in scipy but accepts only 2x2 contingency tables:

```
stats.fisher_exact(prfs, alternative = 'two-sided')
ValueError: The input `table` must be of shape (2, 2).
```

In R there is a function that does exactly that, but how about in Python?
In R:

```
fisher.test(prfs)
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  prfs
p-value = 0.03261
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scipy.stats.chi2_contingency() is the closest you will get.